# Orphan code block throwing Exception in struct

Tags: c++, exception, struct

I was recently asked this question in an interview. Below code, snippet behavior was asked. I mentioned that the code would 
throw an exception that would be caught but it did not turn out to be the right answer.

I have tried debugging this piece of the code snippet and have two questions.

1.
If execution does enter the line try { A a; } then why catch fails to catch the exception?

2.
What is the behavior of this orphan piece of code that does not belong to any method inside the struct? If I put the orphan code 
to be included under the constructor method of B i.e inside B() { } then the exception is caught properly. so how does the execution 
flow handle this? I mean to which method/function stack does the orphan code try catch in B belong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A()
    {
        throw 2;
    }
};

struct B
{
    B()
        // start of orphan code.
        try
        {
            A a;
        }
    catch(int i)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    // end of orphan code.
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    B b;
    cout << "3" << endl;
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "orphan code" is in fact a [function try block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block). Such blocks have a special behavior when used with constructors and destructors: every `catch` block implicitly rethrows the exception, as if the last statement were `throw;` . This is done to make it impossible to use an object that failed to complete construction.

Comment: If that is true Igor, then why the below code does ensure that exception is caught and handled properly.                                            
B() 
{      
 // start of orphan code.
        try
        {
            A a;
        }
     catch(int i)
     {
         cout << i << endl;
     }
     // end of orphan code.
}

Comment: No, that code does not in fact so ensure. [Demo](https://rextester.com/WJGGJ52966) (observe uncaught exception).

Comment: The link you posted is the same as the link I posted. I'm not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: What i was talking about is B() has now a start and end brace with in which try and catch block is there and then it is not same as special case of function try block with constructor in this case.

Comment: What do you mean, "has now"? The code at that link doesn't resemble your description. No braces have magically sprouted since the time I posted it.

Comment: sorry the fork has something wrong , I put the code here. https://rextester.com/RYO53659 , Apologies for confusion.